# Why a wave whose intensity is modulated sinusoidally have different frequency compared to original wave even though intensity depends on amplitude?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, intensity

While experimenting to find the velocity of light, instead of finding the velocity of light, we used the light wave whose intensity was varied sinusoidally and found the velocity of light using the formula c=4fΔx where f is the frequency of the intensity modulated light wave, and Δx is its path difference.
Here this formula was derived by dividing the path difference traversed by the intensity-modulated wave divided by the time taken. It was seen that the frequency of this modulated wave is different, but how is this possible when it is the same wave, and modulation is applied only on intensity which depends on amplitude, not on frequency?
Also, if the frequency of the wave changes on this modulation, how can we measure the velocity of light by measuring the intensity modulated wave? Is it because both have the same velocity as v=fλ? But why do λ and f adjusts so that v remains constant?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You throw a steel ball, the path is parabola. You place a magnet somewhere near the path of the ball and now the path has a kink, di[p, whatever, a "modulation" and is not a parabola anymore, is that surprising? A sinusoid is no more "fundamental" physically than a polynomial or an exponential, it is not a "sacrament", it is a function as any other.